Cannot connect PSQL to local Postgres database
PSQL is failing to connect to Postgres 16 running on the local Fedora 40 Linux server.
I can connect from a remote server or through PGAdmin using pqsl, but not locally. I get the same error when trying to connect to the remote machine using PSQL.
Error:
bash-5.2$ psql
Password for user postgres:
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  parameter "listen_addresses" cannot be changed without restarting the server

postgres.conf:
listen_addresses = '*'
port is default 5432

pg_hba.conf:
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only

local   all             all                                     md5

# IPv4 local connections:

host    all             all             172.22.0.1/16           md5

# IPv6 local connections:

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.

local   replication     all                                     md5
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5

I have restarted postgresql-16 after making any changes (systemctl restart postgresql-16) without any errors.
I also don't see much in the log beside a copy of the connection error.
I have also opened that port in the firewall.
More details
The server with the issue is an Azure VM running Fedora 40, and Postgresql 16. I can connect from a Fedora 37 on premise Lenovo ThinkCentre that has Postgresql 14. I cannot connect from the Fedora 40 to Fedora 37 but can connect from the 37 to the 40 all using the psql command.

try command bash-5.2$ PGOPTIONS='' psql. I have only one idea how you can get such an error, I want to check it.

Just wondering, does it behave the same if you use psql parameters like --host= and --port? And also if you try to connect to loopback ip 127.0.0.1, but also to public ip with --host parameter, are there any differences there?

@Melkij You must be right.

The PGOPTIONS='' worked.  Changing the host and parameters does work.

Sorry, I commented with haste. Changing host and port parameters does NOT work.
Is that the env variable?  echo $PGOPTIONS returns "-i"

After a quite a long search, I found it in /etc/environment.  I'm not sure how it got there but sure enough there was an variable with PGOPTIONS="-i". Per here it was trying to set listen_addresses to '*' but the server was already running, hence the error in the post.
All is right in the world again. Thank you @Melkij for pointing me in the right direction on this!
